# How to use JAXBContext and Marshaller to display XML on the web browser

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I don't not want to create a file ( I do know how to do this but rather than creating a file i want to see the results directly in the browser)

The below code is trying to read a list of films, use the generate Output XML method and send the xml back to my get method which should display the xml in the browser.

My generateOutputXML method works. When i write to the console using m.marshal(filmList, System.out); i can see the expected XML in the console but in the browser I see "model.FilmList@10eb45c4"

```
@WebServlet("/Control")
public class Control extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    public Control() {
        super();
    }

   
    public static FilmList generateOutputXML (ArrayList<Film> films) throws JAXBException, FileNotFoundException {
        
        // create filmList, assigning film
        FilmList filmList = new FilmList();
        filmList.setFilmList(films);

        StringBuffer outputXML = new StringBuffer();
        // create JAXB context and instantiate marshaller
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FilmList.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

        // Write to System.out
        m.marshal(filmList, System.out);
        
        return filmList;
    }
    
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        //response.setContentType("text/xml");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        
        String jsonResult;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        
        FilmDAO fd = new FilmDAO();
        ArrayList<Film> filmList = new ArrayList<Film>();
        
        filmList = fd.getAllFilms();
        jsonResult = gson.toJson(filmList);
        
        FilmList allFilms = new FilmList();

        try {
            allFilms = generateOutputXML(filmList);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException | JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    //jsonResult = gson.toJson(filmList);
    //      out.println(jsonResult);
         out.println("Test");
         out.println(allFilms);

    }


    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    
        doGet(request, response);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're writing the generated XML to `System.out`. No one can see that output in a webapp. It *might* get logged, but users can't see the log.

You should write the generated XML directly to the response writer.

It also seems like you want to alternatively send the response as JSON. That's fine, but you should let the client specify the format. This is often done with HTTP header `Accept`, but can be done with a query parameter instead.

Here is example code for that.

```java
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Determine content type
    String format = request.getParameter("format");
    if (format == null || format.equalsIgnoreCase("XML")) {
        response.setContentType("text/xml; charset=UTF-8");
    } else if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("JSON")) {
        response.setContentType("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    } else {
        throw new ServletException("Unknown format: \"" + format + "\"");
    }

    // Get data
    FilmDAO fd = new FilmDAO();
    ArrayList<Film> films = fd.getAllFilms();

    // Render data directly to response stream
    try (Writer responseWriter = response.getWriter()) {
        if (format == null || format.equalsIgnoreCase("XML")) {

            FilmList filmList = new FilmList();
            filmList.setFilmList(films);

            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FilmList.class);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            m.marshal(filmList, responseWriter);

        } else if (format.equalsIgnoreCase("JSON")) {

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            gson.toJson(films, responseWriter);

        }
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        throw new ServletException("JAXB failed: " + e, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing - so helpful. Thank you ever so much.

Comment: sorry to ping you another question, if the user doesn't want xml or json but wants string / plain text is there a particular library to use or would it just be using the writer and iterating over the object to display it?

Comment: @Reeves62 You'd have to write the code, since you'd have to decide what the string should be. You might have already done so, so maybe the code is just `for (Film film : films) { responseWriter.write(film.toString() + "\r\n"); }`